# The title of the paper does not appear when using the IEEE format

Tags: ieee-style

I am writing a research paper using the IEEE format on overleaf. I am facing a problem with the title, it does not appear even though I used the appropriate command. My code is shown below, please if anyone could help please let me know.

```
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts  
\overrideIEEEmargins
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\title{\LARGE \bf Power Consumption of Mobile Ad-hoc Networks (MANETs)  Protocols}

\author{Nasser Omar}
\end{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your code is not compilable, please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389) of what you are trying to do. Moreover, you should look at the LaTeX example associated to the IEEE class, it would inform you that you need a `\maketitle` command somewhere to make the title and authors appear.

Comment: Aside: If you're using the `IEEEtran` document class, you should remove `\LARGE` and `\bf` from the argument of `\title`.

Comment: Your (non-compilable) code fragment is missing a `\maketitle` directive.

Comment: Remove the `\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}` around the `\title` and `\author`, and use a `\maketitle` after `\author{...}` instead as Mico has suggested?

Comment: @Mico  Thanks a lot for your response. Your pieces of advice were helpful and solved the problem.

Comment: @LianTzeLim Thanks a lot for your response. Your pieces of advice were helpful and solved the problem.